# Increment all members of an array of timestamps in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for a way to update all timestamp members of a column's (`time_start`) array with a fixed interval value of 'x days'.

Would I need to unnest the array first?

The table in question:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.venue (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    time_start character varying(25)[]
);
```

Sample value of `time_start` (truncated, unordered):

```
{2019-05-22T04:12:46,2020-03-19T11:07:43,2020-01-08T03:56:40,2019-09-01T20:29:25,2019-09-29T21:38:18,2019-07-21T16:54:37}
```

Considering an increment of `1 day`, a desired output would be:

```
{2019-05-23T04:12:46,2020-03-20T11:07:43,2020-01-09T03:56:40,2019-09-02T20:29:25,2019-09-30T21:38:18,2019-07-22T16:54:37}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to unnest the array somehow. Or write a function that iterates over the elements. This would be really easy with a properly normalized model.

Comment: I would prefer it be a sql-based approach

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the `create table` statement for the table in questioin,  some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)